# indentationerror expected an indented block function

Tags: python

how can i have a problem.  I'm doing the function that I can rerun

```
def sesver():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
      print("Bir sey de!")
      audio = r.listen(source)
    data = ""
    try:
      data = r.recognize_google(audio, language='tr-tr')
      data = data.lower()
      return data 
    except ValueError:

data = sesver()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add 4 spaces for [indent](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html).

```
def sesver():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Bir sey de!")
        audio = r.listen(source)
        data = ""
        try:
            data = r.recognize_google(audio, language='tr-tr')
            data = data.lower()
            return data 
        except ValueError:
            pass

data = sesver()
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The issue was the missing `pass` statement, not the number of spaces (there is no requirement about that in Python).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your code listing is incorrectly formatted and the function body is actually indented. Your problem then is in `except ValueError:`. It expects an indented block after it. If you simply want to ignore any ValueErrors, write `pass` in the indented block.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
def sesver():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print 'Bir sey de!'
        audio = r.listen(source)
    data = ''
    try:
        data = r.recognize_google(audio, language='tr-tr')
        data = data.lower()
        return data
    except ValueError: # ':' was missing
        pass           # you pass or show exception message


data = sesver()
```

If you are new, try online indentations checkers. It will help to create a clean indented code.

Answer (score -1):

Write on top of code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
```

and into the terminal write:

```
pip install SpeechRecognition
```